# Get Image Format of BLOB in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, image, blob

I am storing images as BLOB type in my DB, however I want to restrict it to only svg types, I know i cannot get the image name or anything from a blob but I assume I can get the format of the image at least, would like to know how to achieve this with oracle SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Oracle is concerned, a `blob` is just a bunch of bytes.  It has no idea whether it's an image or a document or a video so it has no idea what format anything might be.  In theory, you could [look up the specification of the SVG file format](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/) and write some code to try to recognize the file.  How complicated this will be will depend rather heavily on how accurate you want to be in recognizing the file.

It appears that the [SVG document format](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-SVG2-20181004/struct.html) is an XML document that contains a number of `svg` elements so you could do something like convert the `blob` to a XML `clob` and run an XPath expression on that looking for `svg` elements.  That wouldn't guarantee that you were correct-- I can create an XML document that has `svg` elements that isn't an SVG file but it's probably close enough.  Alternately, or in addition, you could look at the XML namespaces in the document to see if the `svg` element is referencing a W3C SVG file format URL (i.e. xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg").

Practically, though, if you care about the format of a `blob` column, it generally makes far more sense to store metadata information in additional columns.  Whatever is loading the data into the `blob` column almost certainly has the ability to populate additional columns like `file_name`, `extension`, `mime_type`, etc. so that you know what the column contains.  You can then rely on those metadata columns rather than trying to parse out the contents of the file.